# Django - Get element within template without field name

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm building a component that is going to be a dynamic table. It means I will have dynamic columns and dynamic data.

What I'm doing so far:

```
fields = [(f.verbose_name, f.name) for f in Car._meta.fields]
data = Car.objects.all()

context['fields'] = fields
context['data'] = data
```

And inside of my django template is something like this:

```
<table class="table">
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        {% for field in fields %}
        <th>{{ field.0 }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
        {% for value in data%}
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            {% for field in fields %}               
            <td>{{ value }}</td>                
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
       {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Where I have my tag `{{ value }}` how can I get my field value without the name? as you can see, I don't know which column I'm iterating.. any ideas?

Comment: So you want something like {{ value.field }} ?

Comment: Obvious stupid question but have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I tried but didn't work because "field" is not an attribute from value..

Comment: Okay well try doing 
{% with f = field.0 %}
<td> {{value.f }} <td>
{% endwith %}

Comment: Hey, didnt work ! Now everything is empty, but looks a nice idea, I think thats the way! hehehe..

Comment: sorry, a lil hard to help debug django apps when you can't run them :p

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in django templates (get a field using a dynamic name). You need to prepare your data in python, so that in the template you would have a list of field values matching the columns. The easiest way to accomplish this is to simply use the values_list queryset method:

```
data = Car.objects.values_list()
```

And then just iterate the list in the template (you might want to change variable names here):

```
{% for field_value in value %}
  <td>{{ value }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

(this replaces the second internal for)